# HTML Function Call not working

Tags: javascript, html

I've been having problems getting my startform() function to work in my below HTML. I can get it to work in JFIDDLE by using the no wrap option. Any ideas why my function call is not working ive tested the JavaScript code separately and it works.

```
    <html>
<title>Paycheck Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="pay.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="midterm.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="paycheck">
<table width=80% align="center" >
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><h1>Your Paycheck Calculator</h1></td>
        <!-- FORM DATE -->
        <td colspan="2"><h2 align="right">Date: <input type="text" id ="formdate" class="date" name="formdate" size="10"></h2></td>
        <td><input type="button" onclick="startform();" value="test"></input></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">This Paycheck Calculator has been provided for you by your
        Human Resources Department. You can use it to figure out your upcoming paycheck
        or to see what impact the following changes would make on your paycheck: if
        you change the number of dependents on you W-2, if you increase or decrease your
        working hours, or if you get a raise. <br /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4"><hr /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="smallcell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="bordrlft"><p class="rght">Hourly Pay Rate:<br /></p></td>
        <td class="bordr"><input name="payrate"></td>
        <td class="bigcell">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="smallcell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="bordrlft"><p class="rght">Number of hours <br />
        worked this week: </p></td>
        <td class="bordr"><input name="hours" ></td>
        <td class="bigcell">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <!--<tr>
        <td class="smallcell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td valign="top" class="bordrlft"><p class="rght">How many <br />
        dependents do<br /> you claim on <br />your taxes?</p></td>
        <td class="bordr">
            <input type="radio" name="tax0" value="zero" onclick="tax_percent();">0<br />
            <input type="radio" name="tax1" value="one" onclick="tax_percent();">1<br />
            <input type="radio" name="tax2" value="two" onclick="tax_percent();">2<br />
            <input type="radio" name="tax3" value="threefour" onclick="tax_percent();">3 - 4<br />
            <input type="radio" name="tax4" value="fivesix" onclick="tax_percent();">5 - 6<br />
            <input type="radio" name="tax5" value="oversix" onclick="tax_percent();">more than 6<br />
        </td>
        <td class="bigcell">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>-->
    <tr> 
        <td colspan="4"><hr /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="right" class="rght">Your tax rate is: </td>
        <td colspan="2" ><input type="text" name="feedback" value="" size="20" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="right" class="rght">Your paycheck will be: </td>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="feedback3" value="" size="20"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="smallcell">&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="2" class="rght"><!-- here is the reset buttons--> 
        <p> <input type="reset" value="clear" name="reset"></p></td>
        <td class="smallcell">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

--------JavaScript code------

```
function today(){ 
    var date = new Date();
    var day = date.getDate();
    document.getElementById("formdate").value = day;
    }
    /*function to get date to load on startup */
function startform(){  
    today();
    /*function to display calculated amount in 2-decimal format */
    }
```

Comment: Please state your problem more clearly

Comment: On the face of it, it seems that it should populate the input with the date when you click the button.  Is the javascript definitely available in `midterm.js` within _the same directory_ as the html file, as that's where it's looking for it?  Do you see any errors logged in the browser console?

Comment: sorry Yea i have double checked the names of everything, that all seems ok. It working in JFIDDLE is throwing me off i feel like something is prohibiting it from working in the browser but ive tried multiple and have installed JavaScript extensions to try to catch any errors.

Comment: *it's not working* - the single most unhelpful phrase you can use.  What isn't working? What is it not doing? What is it doing that it shouldn't be doing? Are you getting console errors in your browser developer tools? Help us to help you

Comment: So ive narrowed it down to something in the JavaScript/HTML file causing me issues i think ive figured out the issue. I was able to strip out everything in my html and was able to get it to work. THis is also just a small part of a bigger project. Thanks For the input

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dLf9qdp3/

Answer (score 0):

So ive narrowed it down to something in the JavaScript/HTML file causing me issues i think ive figured out the issue. I was able to strip out everything in my html and was able to get it to work. THis is also just a small part of a bigger project. Thanks For the input

New code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Paycheck Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="pay.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="midterm.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<form name="paycheck" onclick="startform();">
<table width=80% align="center" >
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><h1>Your Paycheck Calculator</h1></td>
        <!-- FORM DATE -->
        <td colspan="2"><h2 align="right">Date: <input type="text" id ="formdate" class="date" name="formdate" size="10"></input></h2></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
function today(){ 
    var date = new Date();
    var day = date.getDate();
    document.getElementById("formdate").value = day;
    }
    /*function to get date to load on startup */
function startform(){  
    today();
    /*function to display calculated amount in 2-decimal format */
    }

/*function dollars(n) { 
     var dollar = n.toFixed(2);
     return dollar;
}
*/
```

Comment: what you want to do is to populate formdate field on page load using today()?

Comment: Also, there is onclick event for form component in HTML.